# Cannot seem to add Node to Kendo UI TreeView

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I was trying to add Node from textbox to the existing treeview

Input

```
<input id="appendNodeText" value="Node" class="k-textbox">
```

Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" id="addTopLevel">Add Top Level Menu</button>
```

javascript

```
 <script>
     // button handler
      $("#addTopLevel").click(append);

     handleTextBox = function (callback) {
         return function (e) {
            if (e.type != "keypress" || kendo.keys.ENTER == e.keyCode) {
               callback(e);
             }
        };
     };

     var append = handleTextBox(function (e) {
     var selectedNode = treeview.select();
     console.log(selectedNode);
     // passing a falsy value as the second append() parameter
     // will append the new node to the root group
     if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
        selectedNode = null;
     }

     treeview.append({
            text: $("#appendNodeText").val()
            }, selectedNode);
     });
```

So I end up having this click event in which it passes in "append"

To be honest I don't understand the handleTextBox , nor the append

The treeview does "work" but I wonder if it is part of the issue

```
   var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                                expanded: true,
                                dragAndDrop: true,
                                dataSource: homogeneous,
                                dataTextField: "ReportGroupName" //"name" //"id" // "FullName"
                                ,
                                change: function(e) {
                                    console.log("Change", this.select());
                                }
                            });
```

PER an Answer:

I tried this

```
$("#addTopLevel").click(function () {
    console.log('in this');
    if (treeview.select().length) {
        console.log('1');
        treeview.append({
            text: $("#appendNodeText").val()
        }, treeview.select());
    } else {
        //alert("please select tree node");
        console.log('2');
    }
});
```

console.log writes out   'in this'  then  '1'

So i'm not even selecting any node .... something must be wrong

here is my json

`[{"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4}]`

Comment: please create a jsfiddle for the same..

Comment: How do i do that when I am getting data from a mvc controller call , i can see the json from my url  http://localhost:2949/Report/GetReportGroupAssignments

Comment: isn't my solution  working even you have selected an element from the treeview?

Comment: Yes, but essentially it is so heavily dependent on the incoming data.  The hard-coded data is really easy for the most part.   How can I take my json and convert it to the inline tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood you want to append the textbox value as a node to selected node in the treeview. i have created a jsfiddle for the same with working functionality:-

http://jsfiddle.net/GHdwR/468/

click event for button:-

```
$("#addTopLevel").click(function() {
    if (treeview.select().length) {
        treeview.append({
            text: $("#appendNodeText").val()
        }, treeview.select());
    } else {
        alert("please select tree node");
    }
});
```

Comment: I see that the fiddle works.  In mine it does go into the if statement but without even selecting anything.  I guess I want to also be able to add to the very outer level without selecting anything.   Also it does not seem to work with my data,  what can I provide that will show my data?

Comment: I added the code and my json as part of my question at the bottom.  Thanks in advance @Devendra